# PyQt5 QWebview, QWebPage will not loop html5 video

Tags: html, qt, video, pyqt, pyqt5

Running on Windows 10, but problem is in 7 and 8 as well.

The html loaded into the QWebview's QWebPage, the video uses the html 'video' tag, and parameter 'loop'.

```
<video preload="none" loop muted class="video-tag" poster="some_pic.jpg">
    <source src="some_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

If I visit the page on my browser, the video loops as intended.

The QWebView QWebPage will only play the video once, then fallback to a preset .jpg, and if cursor exits the movie and returns, the movie will play again.

I tried setting QWebPage:ToggleMediaLoop action, by calling:

```
self.page().action(QtWebKitWidgets.QWebPage.ToggleMediaLoop).setChecked(True)
```

And verified, by calling the following line before (False) and after (True):

```
self.page().action(QtWebKitWidgets.QWebPage.ToggleMediaLoop).isChecked()
```

From [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebpage.html#ToggleMediaLoop): "Toggles whether the hovered audio or video should loop on completion or not"

Am I not setting the action properly? 
Am I missing a .dll? 
Is "loop" not supported by QtWebKit?

Thank you! =)